# AWS EMR Ganglia dashboard not accessible - 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster

```
response = emr_client.run_job_flow(
    Name="Test dashboards",
    ReleaseLabel='emr-6.2.0',
    LogUri=f"s3://my-bucket/emr_logs/",
    Instances={
        'MasterInstanceType': 'm6g.2xlarge',
        'SlaveInstanceType': 'm6g.2xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 2,
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
        'Ec2SubnetId': emr_config['Instances']['Ec2SubnetId'],
        'AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups': emr_config['Instances']['AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups']
    },
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole=emr_config['JobFlowRole'],
    ServiceRole=emr_config['ServiceRole'],
    StepConcurrencyLevel=1,
    Applications=[
        {"Name":"Spark"},
        {"Name": "JupyterHub"},
        {"Name": "Ganglia"}
    ]
)
```

When I want to view the [dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html) it works ok for jupyterhub/Yarn resource manager/... (i.e.

- `http://master-public-dns-name:8088/`
- `https://master-public-dns-name:9433/`

but when I try to access Ganglia `http://master-public-dns-name/ganglia` I am getting `403 Forbidden`.

Is there any extra setup required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

E: [Know issue but still not fixed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-6x.html) in EMR 6.3.0

`ssh`ing to the master node and running

```
sudo service httpd reload
```

fixes the issue (thanks to @Aleksey!). E: Initially I thought the steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515934/unable-to-view-ganglia-dashboard)) are necessary which is not true.

The gotcha here is that you can't just put this to a bootstrap script because they are executed before software is installed on the cluster. Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211309/is-there-a-way-to-setup-bootstrap-actions-to-run-on-emr-after-core-services-are)
you can create a shell script `s3://my-bucket/fix_ganglia.sh`

```
if [ -f "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ganglia.conf" ]; then
    echo "Setting up ganglia on master node"
    sudo sed -i 's/Order deny,allow/#Order deny,allow/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ganglia.conf
    sudo service httpd reload
fi
```

and configure it as a step with `script-runner.jar`

```
Steps = [{
    'Name': 'Fix Ganglia access',
    'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
    'HadoopJarStep': {
        'Jar': 's3://ap-southeast-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
        'Args': ['s3://my-bucket/fix_ganglia.sh']
    }
}]
```

and this should work.

Comment: The sed command is not necessary.  It doesn't do anything, the default order is "deny,allow". What fixes it (at least on EMR 6.2.0) is reloading the httpd.

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order which shows the default Order is deny,allow.

Comment: seealso https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-630-release.html